My navbar isn´t working with a background Video how can i fix it?
As soon as I put in a background video I cant press my navbar anymore, whats the problem? I also tryed any kind of z-index but it won´t work.
I tryed to remove the video and then it worked but i dont understand why it isnt working with the video in the background.
And it would be realy nice if you could help me with some of my other Questions :)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>fashion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_2_Seite.css" media="all" />
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href= "1-Seite.html" class= logo>fashion</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
                <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
                <a href="#">Über uns</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        
            <video autoplay muted loop src="VideoErsteSeite.mp4"> </video>
        
    
    </body>

                    
                    
</html>

body {
   
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";

}


.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:19px 20px;
    background: #DCdCdC
    z-index: 1001;
}



    
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding:20px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
    
}

.navbar a {

    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 400px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    z-index: 1001;
}


can you please post the stylesheet as well?

Pls post your css file and make a minimal reproducible snippet using <> would be better for help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

sorry, accidentally posted both html files

In your CSS .header's background is missing a semicolon at the end.
This is causing the CSS to ignore the z-index property.
background: #DCdCdC
z-index: 1001;

should be
background: #DCdCdC;
z-index: 1001;

I'm surprised your editor didn't pick up on this and give you a red squiggly line.
